# Javascript email name /domain length

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have created a project that requires validation of a form with Javascript. Everything works great except for one little part and it is confusing me. Maybe its just the wording of the assignment so I thought I'd ask on here. I am new to Javascript so don't yell at me if I a doing it wrong! I am still learning. What an exciting language!

Utilizing the below code I am able ensure that the email address and confirm email address don't exceed 252 characters as required by the instructions. However part of the instruction states that the name part can't exceed 64 characters and the domain cant exceed 252 characters.

I left a lot of code out but don't think it's needed for this part. If you want to see the rest let me know. It's quite long since I have about a dozen fields i am validating.

Question 1: I tested it.. manually.. and it allows the part before @ to exceed 64 characters. How do I prevent that?

Question 2: Similar ad question 1. How do I prevent the domain (after the @) to not exceed 252 characters?

code:

```
enter code here

            var email = document.getElementById('emailAddress');
            var cEmail = document.getElementById('cEmail');
            var emailconf1 = document.getElementById('emailAddress').value;
            var emailconf2 = document.getElementById('cEmail').value;
            var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (!filter.test(email.value)) 
            {
                alert('Please provide a valid email address');
                email.focus;
                return false;
            }
        if (!filter.test(cEmail.value)) 
            {
                alert('Please provide a valid email address in the confirm email box');
                email.focus;
                return false;
            }   
        if (emailconf1 != emailconf2)
            {
                alert('Passwords do not match')     
                return false;
            }   
        if (emailconf1.length>252 || emailconf2.length>252)
            {
            alert('Your email address is greater than 252 chracters')
            return false;
            }

        }
```

Floyd

Comment: I would troll the teacher by making two inputs, one for name and one for domain with maxlength :-)

Comment: Can you add the html?

Comment: I tried but cant figure out how to put it in here so you can see the code part..